# What does 正宗で大根を切る。 言い出しっぺ。 mean?

Tags: translation

I'm not sure if this off-topic for this site but I would like to know what "正宗で大根を切る。  言い出しっぺ。" means. I tried translating it through google but I don't think it translated it properly. I found this on a user's profile.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think these two phrases are related, even though they're both in Robusto's profile.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11598/is-senator-alan-simpsons-quote-a-sparrows-belch-in-the-midst-of-a-typhoon

Read the comments.

Comment: It would help of you could be specific about what you don't understand, or what you've translated so far. As it is I'm afraid I'm going to vote to close as this is too close to a pure translation question.

Comment: @silvermaple The reason as to why I asked this question was because the translation through google did not make sense to me. Therefore, I asked the question this site. However, if the question does not adhere to site's format then by all means, close it.

Comment: @silvermaple For what it's worth (and after checking the [relevant FAQ-related information on translations](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-and-usage/799#799),) it would seem to me that this type of question is more than a standard "dictionary lookup" translation... because it ultimately involves the meaning behind the ideas presented (not just the words in and of themselves.)  In other words, it's not necessarily a word-for-word translation question. :)

Comment: @silvermaple At the same time, I'm not without at least some bias in this overall post... :) so, please take my earlier response with a grain of salt :|

Comment: @summea: I did sort of debate with myself as the phrases do seem to be idiomatic which is a bit more than a standard dictionary look-up. I don't think it will be closed at this point, especially with you're very good answer :) @ gekkostate, next time if you can just tell us what Google translated it to, and/or why that doesn't sit right/what you don't understand, I think it would be perfectly fine >^.^<

Comment: @silvermaple Good advice for future questions :)

Comment: @silvermaple I will keep that in mind!

Comment: For what it's worth, *all* the sayings in my profile are unrelated to each other. That's why I preface the section with "Some of the smartest things people have ever said." YMMV.

Comment: Actually, I just looked, and those sayings come *before* the "smartest things" sentence. But everything is on a separate line, and none of the three English sentences with the Japanese are related, either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「大根{だいこん}を正宗{まさむね}で切る{きる}。」 essentially means "Using a precious sword ([a Masamune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masamune)) to cut an everyday daikon."  It's [an example](http://kotowaza-allguide.com/ta/daikonwomasamunedekiru.html) of using something very important for something mundane.  For example, if someone earned a [Doctor of Philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Philosophy) but the only job they ended up doing after graduation involved teaching a kindergarten class, this expression could be used.

「言{い}い出{だ}しっぺ」 is an expression that has to do with the [idea](http://zokugo-dict.com/02i/iidasippe.htm) that if a speaker initially brings up an issue in conversation (or initially puts the blame of something on someone else,) it probably means that the problem lies with the speaker.  In other words, *"He who smelt it, dealt it."*

Comment: Could you please provide some text that can show me to pronounce it?

Comment: @gekkostate Sure thing; sorry about that!  In romaji, those phrases would be: "daikon (w)o masamune de kiru" and the second phrase would be: "iidashippe" :)

Comment: Yup, you get the prize.